# EhCacheManager bean return alway Null

Tags: spring, ehcache, jcache

Hello so I am trying to create EhCacheManager and configure the bean so I can inject it in my code

the problem is I always have a null pointer whenever I wanna use the bean to get cache ( pre-configured in ehcache.xml)

My EhCacheManager bean

```
<bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" id="MyDefaultCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

ehcache.xml

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <!-- By default, Ehcache stored the cached files in temp folder. -->
    <!-- <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" /> -->

    <!-- Ask Ehcache to store cache in this path -->
    <diskStore path="c:\\cache" />

    <!-- Sample cache named cache1
    This cache contains a maximum in memory of 10000 elements, and will expire
    an element if it is idle for more than 5 minutes and lives for more than
    10 minutes.

    If there are more than 10000 elements it will overflow to the
    disk cache, which in this configuration will go to wherever java.io.tmp is
    defined on your system. On a standard Linux system this will be /tmp" -->
    <cache name="simpleCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
        eternal="false"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
        timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

injecting the bean

```
@Autowired
EhCacheCacheManager  ehCacheManager ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/ehcache.xml"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you share the console logs please? The project doesn't compile or the server doesn't start?

Comment: actually my application is deployed successfully with no errors the problem is when I want to execute a webservice that is trying to use ehCacheManager bean to get a specific cache declared in ehcache.xml I get a null pointer I have already debugged and the value injected ( in ehCacheManager ) is null so I guess I am missing something in the declaration.

Comment: I see ok. I just doubt from value="classpath:/ehcache.xml". May be you can put that ehcache.xml into another directory not directly to the classpath. Or you can try to delete that backslash (/).

Comment: i have removed it but stil have null bean

Comment: Can you share the code that throws Null Pointer Exception and the console logs please?